# Group internal automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

How to prove that group of internal automorphism of group $G$ isomorphic to $G$/$\Bbb Z(G)$?
Have no idea, need you help and advice

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Given $g \in G$, let $\phi_g : G \to G$ be the conjugation map $x \mapsto g x g^{-1}$.  Consider the map $\Phi : G \to \text{Aut}(G)$ given by $g \mapsto \phi_g$.  Now show the kernel of this map is $Z(G)$, the center of $G$, and apply the First Isomorphism Theorem.

Comment: I will be pleased, if you write a full solution. Can't inderstand, how to use your hint

Comment: My hint is quite complete, so I'd prefer if you fill in the remaining details.  If you have questions about the hint, I'm happy to clarify.